# Why does subversion switch to the parent directory when doing a commit

Tags: svn, shell, directory

When I do a svn commit from the unix command line it switches to the parent directory before opening up the editor. This caues great confusion when I do a shell escape since I'm not where I think I am.

What is the reason for this behavior ?

(Edit) Below screen captures show this happening in the lowest directory and not happening in the topmost one

```
svn --version svn, version 1.5.5 (r34862)

test: svn checkout file:///export/home/svn/xxx/a
A    a/b
A    a/b/c
A    a/b/c/new
Checked out revision 8882.

test: cd a/b/c
test: pwd
/home/geretz/test/a/b/c
test: echo changed > new
test: svn commit

--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

M    c/new
~
~
:!pwd
/home/geretz/test/a/b

Hit ENTER or type command to continue
```

abort the editing session, try to commit from top level directory

```
test: pwd
/home/geretz/test/a/b/c
test: cd ../..
test: pwd
/home/geretz/test/a
test: svn commit

--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

M    b/c/new
~
~
:!pwd
/home/geretz/test/a

Hit ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: svn --version
svn, version 1.5.5 (r34862)

Comment: Does it switch to the immediate parent, or the root of the working copy? If it's the latter, I bet you could figure out why...

Comment: but if the directory above it isn't under svn control it stays in the current directory

Comment: Are you using svn directly or via a shell script ? Calling the native svn client on unix ?

Comment: I am calling the native svn client on unix

Comment: Will you include the command you are running, including a synopsis of the directory structure, and an approximation of the editor's buffer when it opens?

Comment: As an extension of @Zachary's question, please also indicate which directory was the current working directory when you issued the `commit` command.

Comment: @zachary,  I edited the question to show the requested info

Answer (score 4):

If you browse svn sources, you find that `svn commit` is handled by `svn_cl__commit` function in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.5.x/subversion/svn/commit-cmd.c. Actual function which takes care about splitting pathes to 'basename' and 'dirname' is `svn_wc_get_actual_target`. This function is declared in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.5.x/subversion/include/svn_wc.h and has following comment:

```
/** Conditionally split @a path into an @a anchor and @a target for the
 * purpose of updating and committing.
 *
 * @a anchor is the directory at which the update or commit editor
 * should be rooted.
 *
 * @a target is the actual subject (relative to the @a anchor) of the
 * update/commit, or "" if the @a anchor itself is the subject.
 *
 * Allocate @a anchor and @a target in @a pool.
 */
```

And finally in file http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.5.x/subversion/libsvn_wc/update_editor.c we can see following comment:

```
Updates are accomplished by driving an editor, and an editor is
"rooted" on a directory.  So, in order to update a file, we need to
break off the basename of the file, rooting the editor in that
file's parent directory, and then updating only that file, not the
other stuff in its parent directory.

Secondly, we look at the case where we wish to update a directory.
This is typically trivial.  However, one problematic case, exists
when we wish to update a directory that has been removed from the
repository and replaced with a file of the same name.  If we root
our edit at the initial directory, there is no editor mechanism for
deleting that directory and replacing it with a file (this would be
like having an editor now anchored on a file, which is disallowed).

All that remains is to have a function with the knowledge required
to properly decide where to root our editor, and what to act upon
with that now-rooted editor.  Given a path to be updated, this
function should conditionally split that path into an "anchor" and
a "target", where the "anchor" is the directory at which the update
editor is rooted (meaning, editor->open_root() is called with
this directory in mind), and the "target" is the actual intended
subject of the update.

svn_wc_get_actual_target() is that function.

...

As it turns out, commits need to have a similar check in place,
too, specifically for the case where a single directory is being
committed (we have to anchor at that directory's parent in case the
directory itself needs to be modified)
```

Comment: If you need to have a predictable working directory when writing your message, it looks like your best bet is to create your commit message and save it to a file *before* you do the commit, and then commit via `svn commit --file commit_log.txt` to use it.  This is essentially what happens behind the scenes anyway, only the file is temporary and is auto-deleted after the commit completes.